# How to convert string to integer with ConvertTo-Json?

Tags: json, powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I am using PowerShell to convert a CSV file to a JSON format. The problem is the CSV wraps double quotes around the column values, even integers. How do I convert them to integers during the conversion process?

This is the script I am using to convert a directory of *.csv files to *.json:

```
Get-ChildItem .\*.csv | Foreach-Object {
  $basename = $_.BaseName
  import-csv $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Foreach {$_ -creplace '"NULL"','null'} | Out-File ".\$basename.json"
}
```

This is my source CSV:

```
"Id","Name","Active"
"1","Test 1","1"
"2","Test 2","0"
"3","Test 3","1"
```

And here is what it outputs:

```
[
{"Id":"1","Name":"Test 1","Active":"1"}
{"Id":"2","Name":"Test 2","Active":"0"}
{"Id":"3","Name":"Test 3","Active":"1"}
]
```

How do I make it output this instead?:

```
[
{"Id":1,"Name":"Test 1","Active":1}
{"Id":2,"Name":"Test 2","Active":0}
{"Id":3,"Name":"Test 3","Active":1}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that's happening is that **Import-Csv** creates an object with a string property for each column, so **ConvertTo-Json** is giving you quoted strings. You could use **Select-Object** between **Import-Csv** and **ConvertTo-Json** to recast the number properties as integers, but I think the simplest way to do it is to add a regex replace in your **foreach** block:

```
import-csv $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | 
    Foreach {$_ -creplace '"NULL"','null' -replace ':"([0-9]+)"',':$1'} | 
        Out-File ".\$basename.json"
```